# css and alignment for a search bar with multiple fields

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a search bar for my forms.

I have an area which is 792px and I usually put a series of labels and fields I use for search purposes. Usually I put each element in a `<div>` and set the style of it to `float:left` and define the width of it. I've never really liked it but, since I am not an expert with CSS, I've learned to accept it.

Now I need to add a few more fields than usual and I would like an element to go on the second line (Label4 and it's field) but I am having troubles doing that.

What is the best, simplest solution to implement something like this considering that I would like to avoid using tables?

[image: search bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the clear attribute on the div containing the 4th input

```
clear: left;
```